# How can I make it so Edit2D lines do not resize when viewer is zoomed in and out?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Long story short: I want to set Edit2D polyline tool's line width to 6" based on calibration sizing and have it stay that size in the viewer no matter the camera zoom.

---

I'm using the edit2d library to allow drawing. I need to be able to set the line width for the polyline tool and have it stay at that width similar to how markups stay a set size when drawn. The default functionality of the edit2d polyline tool is for the line to be resized on camera changes and so it grows and shrinks depending on zoom.

I tried setting  `edit2DTools.polylineTool.style.isScreenSpace = false;` which works, however, trying to set the specific size is difficult as it ends up being a decimal less then 1 and I can't find a correlation from the calibration, page size, etc. to allow me to dynamically set the size the same on different models.

---

I also found this in the Edit2D Snapper's code, but I can't figure out what's happening here to replicate it on the polyline tool. It seems to be doing what I want to do.

[image: Edit2D Snapper]

Any help or ideas at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be working for me:

```js
async function setLineWidth(viewer) {
  let mt = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Measure");
  if (!mt.sharedMeasureConfig.calibrationFactor) {
    console.log("Has not been calibrated yet");
    return;
  }

  let edit2d = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Edit2D');

  let pt1 = {x:0, y:0, z:0}, pt2 = {x:6, y:0, z:0};
  viewer.model.pageToModel(pt1, pt2, 0 /*viewport id*/, true /*reverse*/);
  let style = edit2d.defaultTools.polylineTool.style;
  style.lineWidth = (pt2.x - pt1.x) / mt.calibration.scaleFactor;
}
```

Here is a video showing it in action: https://youtu.be/DIaKugvQdm4

As you can see first the `lineWidth` of the `polylineTool` is not what you want, but after setting what **6"** should be in the drawing, I can set it to the same width and all is fine.

Here is a **zip** file with the **html** including the **JavaScript** code and the test **PDFs** I used: https://github.com/adamenagy/Container/blob/master/Edit2dTest.zip

Comment: That worked perfectly with the isScreenSpace = false. Thanks!

Comment: To add to this, when I use a line style that's not solid (say a dotted line) it is buggy. The spacing is off and doesn't work proper. Is there a way to fix that?

[See this example picture](https://ibb.co/3fLfNj2)

Comment: What exactly do I have to change in the code I provided to achieve this result?

Comment: Thanks for the response!

To set line style you can just change this property on the tool:
`edit2dExtension.defaultTools.polylineTool.style.lineStyle = 4;`

It was working to have a proper dot-line-dot-line style until I switch  `isScreenSpace` to `false` which is necessary for the above solution i believe.

Comment: any chance you can look into it?

Comment: Engineering is looking into providing a way to make thick dashed/dotted lines look good too. Don't know when exactly that might make it into production.